# JAXB adapter which return xml node or raw xml text instead object

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Is it possible:

```
Class Qwe {
    @SuperAdapter
    Map<String, String> prms
}
```

after marshalling:

```
<qwe>
    <prms>
        <prm>
             <name>qwe</name>
             <val>zxc</val>
        </prm>
        <prm>
             <name>tyu</name>
             <val>ghj</val>
        </prm>
        ...
    </prms>
</qwe>
```

I can solve this problem if I have access to the DOM or insert ram xml part.
Or advise me the best solution.
I can solve it via subclasses but I do not think that is a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Please see [this post](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/03/jaxb-and-javautilmap.html) by Blaise Doughan. Snippets:

```
package blog.map;

import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {

    private Map<String, Address> addressMap = new HashMap<String, Address>();

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="addresses")
    public Map<String, Address> getAddressMap() {
        return addressMap;
    }

    public void setAddressMap(Map<String, Address> addressMap) {
        this.addressMap = addressMap;
    }

}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customer>
    <addresses>
        <entry>
            <key>shipping</key>
            <value>
                <street>2 B Road</street>
            </value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <key>billing</key>
            <value>
                <street>1 A Street</street>
            </value>
        </entry>
    </addresses>
</customer>
```

Comment: How can I change name of entry node?

Comment: I think you can't. Seems to be hardcoded: https://github.com/gf-metro/jaxb/blob/3461152ffe39baf32b8550d47d18d58cdbc139c5/jaxb-ri/runtime/impl/src/main/java/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/runtime/property/SingleMapNodeProperty.java#L107-L109